# How to list only matched subdocuments in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm new in mongoose. I tried many queries but couldn't get correct result.
My schema looks like this:

```
{
 course_name: "Test 1",
 students: [
  {name: "Sam", age: 5},
  {name: "Don", age: 7}
 ]
},
{
 course_name: "Test 2",
 students: [
  {name: "Paul", age: 7}
 ]
}
```

In this example I have 2 documents. Every course document contains students data inside of it.
I'm trying to find all students in all courses which their ages are 7. But in queries I tried, it returns Sam too.

Here's an example of which I'm expecting:

```
{name: "Paul", age: 7},
{name: "Don", age: 7}
```

And here's what I'm getting.

```
{name: "Paul", age: 7},
{name: "Sam", age: 5},
{name: "Don", age: 7}
```

My query:

```
const getStudents = await Courses.aggregate([
    {$match: {'students.age': myAge}},
    {$unwind: '$students'},
    {$project: {name: '$students.name', age: '$students.age'}}
  ]);
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a common mistake think that if you match by a nested value (in this case `students.age`) you will get the nested value you want but it doesn't work like this.

You are doing `$match` query before `$unwind` so you are getting all documents where exists any object into `students` array where `age` is 7. That is, the whole document1 pass to the next stage. The array `students` with two values go to next tsage because one of them match the criteria and then, the object is matched.

So, to be clearer, you are doing a `$match` stage where you are saying: "Give me all documents where exist an student which age is 7". Then, the first document match the criteria because one of the students match the filter, and is returned the whole document, not only the object in the array that matches.

You can match after the unwind and you will get the desired output.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4djCFPGCkn7)

Answer (score 2):

@J.F. does a good job explaining why your approach is not correct. Anyway i want to show you how you can achieve the same result using the $filter.

> Selects a subset of an array to return based on the specified
> condition. Returns an array with only those elements that match the
> condition. The returned elements are in the original order.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    students: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$students",
        as: "student",
        cond: {
          $eq: [
            "$$student.age",
            7
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "course_name": "Test 1",
    "students": [
      {
        "age": 7,
        "name": "Don"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "course_name": "Test 2",
    "students": [
      {
        "age": 7,
        "name": "Paul"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```